# Ordered Logit with Fixed Effects in R

Tags: r, mlogit, mass

I am trying to implement fixed effects to ordered logit. I know there is a polr function of the MASS package but I have not found the way to implement fixed effects to polr function. I will use country and year as fixed effects. (I have almost 50 years and 150 countries). Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: check out the `ordinal` package

Comment: Fixed-effects can be achieved in R by using the Country as a dummy (ie. `factor`) in your formula, so you are good to go with `MASS::polr`